# PermissionError with pytesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, permission-denied

My code:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Programs/tesseract'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("test.png")))
```

I get the error: **PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied**

I then ran the program as administrator, and received the same error.
I also changed the permissions of the tesseract folder.

I installed pytesseract using the Python interpreter in **Pycharm**, and also downloaded the binary from Windows [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-with-LSTM#400-alpha-for-windows), using the second option.  I extracted the zip folder in **C:\Programs**

What is causing the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a `TESSDATA_PREFIX` in your system variables to your tessdata folder. Mine is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`.

[image: TESSDATA_PREFIX system variable]

Comment: Note, for programs like PyCharm and many others, you need to also close the program and re-open it after setting the system environment variable.

Answer (score 20):

After spending few hours, I found the issue. I am using Win 10 with Python 3.6

```
img = Image.open('sample1.jpg')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

tesseract.exe executable has to be appended to pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd

fyi, earlier I also gave full rights to Tesseract-OCR folder but it may not be required

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure this is the full path of your executable?

```
C:/Programs/tesseract
```

Because it looks like the path to the executable's folder. Check with the windows explorer what the full path of the executable is and put it in that line:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Programs/tesseract/tesseract.exe'
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but with no result. I still get an error: `pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \\Programs\\tesseract\\tessdata/eng.traineddata')`

Comment: That is a different error, now the executable is being found. Have you checked if that file `eng.traineddata` exists in the `tessdata` folder? I checked the zip file you said you downloaded and the file is not included there, so you might need to follow a tutorial to know how to set up tesseract for first use (check specifically for how to train it or download an already trained config).

Answer (score 1):

This problem only happens in the case where you set environment variables to direct folder

`'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR'`

You can say it's not the full path you have to open Tesseract-OCR and click open tessdata. This means you have to save path

`'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata'`