# Permission denied when reading a image-text in pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as pt

pt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200328.exe"

image = cv2.imread("NormalText.jpg")

text = pt.image_to_string(image)
print(text)
```

I am trying to convert this image to a string, but this error showed up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonFile/Image-Text.py", line 8, in <module>
    text = pt.image_to_string(image)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 370, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 282, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 253, in run_tesseract
    raise e
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 250, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200328.exe'
```

What should I do? please let me know, it would be greatly appreciate it.

Comment: you can limited access to run the process. try with sudo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError with pytesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536361/permissionerror-with-pytesseract)

Comment: Doesn't work when I used sudo.

Comment: This is not a Python question but an OS question. What's your OS: Linux? What permissions, user and group is that file? What user are you running as?

Comment: I'm using Mac osx Mojave, and I'm already in admin permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
import pytesseract as ts
from PIL import Image

img=Image.open("NormalText.jpg")
text=ts.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

It works for me

Comment: I think it does, because I can't seem to install pytesseract. When I do "pip install pytesseract" or "pip3 install pytesseract" my python version doesn't think it's install. I'm using python 3.9.0 and the pip's version is 20.2.4. What can I do with this error? I also used sudo.

Comment: What should my python version be? This error also happened to some of my other codes.

Comment: I am using ```python 3.7.4```

Comment: Well, before 3.8.5 worked for me so I'll change back to that.