# Why there is a permisson denied error while using node-tesseract-ocr?

Tags: node.js, ocr, tesseract

I am using node-tesseract-ocr library for using ocr for my node js project. I installed `tesseract-ocr` in my machine(windows) using `choco` and then `node-tesseract-ocr` using npm. While requesting that particular route I am getting the following error

```
Error, cannot read input file "myActualPath": Permission denied
Error during processing.
```

This is the code I am using

```
const config = {
  lang: 'eng',
  oem: 1,
  psm: 3,
};

    tesseract
      .recognize(__dirname, `../public/data/${reciept}`, config)
      .then((text) => {
        serialResponse = text.match(new RegExp(serial, 'g'));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the tesseract-OCR path in your environment variables, and restart your IDE

**Note**, for programs like PyCharm and many others, you need to also close the program and re-open it after setting the system environment variable - As told by silas in another post similar to this one.
You can refer that post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536361/permissionerror-with-pytesseract) .

Make sure to import the necessary packages in your module

> import pytesseract

> import argparse

> import cv2

Then construct the argument parser and parse the arguments.

`ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()`

`ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image to be OCR'd")`

`args = vars(ap.parse_args())`

**Note** The first Python import you’ll notice in this script is pytesseract (Python Tesseract), a Python binding that ties in directly with the Tesseract OCR application running on your system. The power of pytesseract is our ability to interface with Tesseract rather than relying on ugly os.cmd calls as we needed to do before pytesseract ever existed.
For additional [reference](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/08/23/your-first-ocr-project-with-tesseract-and-python/#:%7E:text=Learn%20how%20to%20import%20the,text%20results%20on%20our%20terminal).

Comment: The environment variable is there. Also I have restarted the IDE as well as laptop

Comment: Have you made necessary imports in your module i.e., import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2

Comment: I am using OCR for a node js project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909935/16436372...checkout this one, might be the solution for your problem then.